# correct use of @specialized in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement a method that can accept a `Seq` of `Int` and `Double`. I heard that this can be done using `Numeric` however I read about an annotation called `@specialized` in a Scala book.

So I tried implementing a method as follows

```
def getMedian[@specialized(Int, Double) T](s:Seq[T]):T = {
  s.sorted match {
    case y:Seq[T] if (y.length % 2 == 0) => y(0) + y(1) / 2
  }
}
```

However Scala doesn't recognise the `+` operation because type hinting seems to think `T` is a `String`.

Note: I have simplified the equation for readability. It no longer represents a median calculation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply can't use `@specialized` for this. Your code still has to compile if `@specialized` is removed; the annotation tells the compiler to *also* generate specialized versions for `T = Int` and `T = Double`. So you still need `Numeric`.

(So far as I understand, in this case `@specialized` is basically useless because `Seq` and `Numeric` aren't specialized.)